# Twitter "Cancel and return to app " issue

Tags: android, twitter4j

[image]

This is the first page of twitter login, when i am clicking on **cancel and return to app**
My application get force close. 
M using Twitter4J for this
Kindly suggest me what can be issue.

M using this code.

```
void OAuthLogin() {
        try {

            twitter = new TwitterFactory().getInstance();
            twitter.setOAuthConsumer(consumerKey, consumerSecret);
            requestToken = twitter.getOAuthRequestToken(CALLBACKURL);
            String authUrl = requestToken.getAuthenticationURL();
            this.startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri
                    .parse(authUrl)));
        } catch (TwitterException ex) {
        Log.e("in Main.OAuthLogin", ex.getMessage());
        }
    }


@Override
    protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
        super.onNewIntent(intent);
        Uri uri = intent.getData();
        if (uri != null && uri.toString().contains(CALLBACKURL)) {
            try {
                String verifier = uri.getQueryParameter("oauth_verifier");
                AccessToken accessToken = twitter.getOAuthAccessToken(
                        requestToken, verifier);
                String token = accessToken.getToken(), secret = accessToken
                        .getTokenSecret();
                twitter.setOAuthAccessToken(token, secret);

                twitter.updateStatus(base_link_url);
            this.displayTimeLine(token, secret); // after everything,
            } catch (TwitterException ex) {
                                }
        }
    }
```

My Manifest File:M using this code for my class

```
<activity android:name=".Test" android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:launchMode="singleTask" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <data android:scheme="gauravmusic" android:host="twitt" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

MY Callback Url:which m using in my code

```
private final String CALLBACKURL = "gauravmusic://twitt";
```

Now Suggest me where m going wrong.

After research i found that ,

```
            if (uri != null && uri.toString().contains(CALLBACKURL))
{

}
```

if i change this condition to

```
if (uri != null && uri.getScheme().toString().contains(CALLBACKURL_SCHEME)) {
}
```

**Cancel,and return to app** working fine now, but now i am unable to post tweet on my wall.
i add both condition together like that

```
   if (uri != null && uri.getScheme().toString().contains(CALLBACKURL_SCHEME) || uri.toString().contains(CALLBACKURL)) {

}
```

its also not working..
Kindly suggest me.

Hi i found answer. i find a pattern that when **Cancel and Retun to app**  link is clicked then this code is executed. In this case we are not login so we cant find value of String Verifier, and its gives NullPointer Exception.

```
if (uri != null && uri.toString().contains(CALLBACKURL)) {
            try {
                String verifier = uri.getQueryParameter("oauth_verifier");
                AccessToken accessToken = twitter.getOAuthAccessToken(
                        requestToken, verifier);
                String token = accessToken.getToken(), secret = accessToken
                        .getTokenSecret();
                twitter.setOAuthAccessToken(token, secret);

                twitter.updateStatus(base_link_url);
            this.displayTimeLine(token, secret); // after everything,
            } catch (TwitterException ex) {
                                }
        }
```

I change this line to

```
if (uri != null && uri.getScheme().toString().contains(CALLBACKURL_SCHEME)&& !uri.toString().contains("denied"))
```

After some research i found that when we click on **Cancel and return to app** link its uri is like that

```
DEBUG/URI!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!(5174): gauravmusic://twittdenied=FjgW7QQYpFDI03sDvIc5I1w6w2Xv67TFI9sKW1OyA
```

And when we are sucessully login then Uri is like that

```
08-17 10:31:19.182: DEBUG/URI(5278): gauravmusic://twitt?oauth_token=pm0E10vayzTViLGQpGZwwpIKhQ9aqwLrEBggiJ7vvPY&oauth_verifier=cHiWkuiQfygmlPeC7B6fNbiqv34gkPIdWctlavzGo80
```

Then i add condition

**!uri.toString().contains("denied")**(bcz when we are not login uri contains a word "denied")

Its work fine for me. 
Now when i click on **Cancel and Return to app**  , it will not reach to this line or in this loop .
    String verifier = uri.getQueryParameter("oauth_verifier");

Now everything works fine. Suggest me if any better idea is for handle this.I dont want to depend on Uri's "denied" word.

Comment: Please post some code and the stacktrace from your logcat.

Comment: It could be anything, couldn't it.  A bug, probably.   I'm baffled how you expect anybody to be able to help you when you provide no evidence.  Perhaps you think only one single thing could be the cause.

Comment: Duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7040043/twitter-cancel-and-return-to-app-link-of-login-page-gives-force-close-closed

Comment: ys..but i tried to delete old one question, but its not delete,Actually my question is without code, so people marked it as uncleared and ranked me negative , also close my question. So i delete this question and upload another one.

Comment: Source code and explanation: http://www.anddev.org/advanced-tutorials-f21/sending-a-tweet-t54389.html

Answer (score 1):

Check this link for Twitter Integration in Android Application.

It works great and perfectly.

Ensure that you gave some Dummy Callback in the Field CallBack URL in the Settings page of your Application.

[Integrating Twitter in Android Application](http://www.android10.org/index.php/articleslibraries/291-twitter-integration-in-your-android-application)

Edit :

I guessed what is happening in our your code , If you cancel the App from Authorization then there will be no value for below verifier

```
String verifier = uri.getQueryParameter("oauth_verifier");
```

Since there is no value it will throws **NULL POINTER EXCEPTION** and it will go from **Try** to **Catch** block, hence

```
 twitter.updateStatus(base_link_url);
```

will no reached

so the Tweet is not posted.

If you need to check this add come **Log** to **Catch Block** so that you can see what is happening.
`

Comment: Can't get you.. What you need?

Comment: sorry, i add some line in my question, chk it....i cant change my code  , my application is big and i cant add five files and four jar files in it. i have to modify this code. Kindly suggest me .

Comment: @Gaurav Gupta I changed ma answer check it.

Comment: ys venky, ur right that String verifier have no value so its giving Null Pointer Exception. its strange when i use ***if(uri != null && uri.toString().contains(CALLBACKURL))*** ,cancel and return to app is not working, i can post sucessfully and when i use ***if (uri != null && uri.getScheme().toString().contains(CALLBACKURL_SCHEME))*** then i cant post anything. Try and Catch cant stop force close here.  i manage it with some modification in these condition.Thanks for help. I am posting answer now , i hope it will help others.

Comment: @GauravGupta let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2564/discussion-between-venky-and-gaurav-gupta)